# mongodb update() modifies only 1st found value

Tags: mongodb

Please advice which command is more suitable to update many fields, or what is wrong with query below.
Query updates only price with value:23

```
db.products.update( {"for":"ac3"}, {$inc:{"price":2}} )

> db.products.find({},{for:1,price:1})
{ "_id" : "ac3", "price" : 200 }
{ "_id" : "ac7", "price" : 320 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bf9"), "price" : 23, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bfa"), "price" : 12 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bfb"), "price" : 38, "for" : [ "ac3", "ac7", "ac9", "qp7",
"qp8", "qp9" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bfc"), "price" : 12.5, "for" : "ac3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bfd"), "price" : 12, "for" : "ac3" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bfe") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15bff") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15c00") }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("507d95d5719dbef170f15c01") }
{ "_id" : "ac9", "price" : 333 }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the [`multi`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#multi-parameter) parameter to `true`:

```
db.products.update({ "for": "ac3" }, { $inc: { "price": 2 } }, { "multi": true });
```